# Google App Engine login fails with error 500

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, http-status-code-500

I have an appengine (Java) app with the ability to sign in via Google. For this I use
[UserServiceFactory.getUserService().createLoginURL(...)](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/users/UserService.html#createLoginURL-java.lang.String-).

This has been working fine so far, and still works well locally (using `mvn appengine:run`) but on production it consistently throws a generic 500 while on `/_ah/conflogin?state=~AJKiYcHHHXI45-...` (the 5th URL of the login process, while already being logged in with Google) and I can find nothing relevant in the Logs Explorer at https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/...

I've since even updated to the latest https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.appengine/appengine-api-1.0-sdk/2.0.10 but the problem remains.

Where should I look at to solve this issue?

Comment: Seems the issue has returned! https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35895145?pli=1

Comment: Yes, Same error for me

Comment: I would suggest checking the Google App Engine Logs Explorer to investigate the issue further. You can also check the App Engine Task Queue to see if there are any tasks that could be causing the issue. Finally, it could be worth looking at the App Engine Admin Console to see if there are any errors with the service or configuration that could be causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

To find the root cause of this issue, you can find the logs for this error will be helpful.

In this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/query-library#gae-filters) there is a sample query that you could try to check for logs error with status 500.

```
resource.type="gae_app" AND
log_id("appengine.googleapis.com/request_log") AND
httpRequest.status>=500
```

Alternatively you could also try running ‘gcloud app logs read’ as mentioned in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/logs/read) to see if you get any logs.

The [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35895145?pli=1) mentioned by Rez in comment is marked as Fixed and after checking your issue I think it also relates to the same issue tracker. As it closed I suggest to get your issue resolved I recommend to raise [new issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/) by referencing the fixed one or else you may raise [support ticket with google](https://support.google.com/)

Comment: Thanks. `httpRequest.status>=500` returns 0 results, when `httpRequest.status>=200` returns tons of results. I believe there are no errors logged. I'll try opening a ticket.

Comment: Yes, no errors logged, I opened a ticket, they said it was an issue and it is fixed now. below is the reply. "This issue appears to relate to an ongoing issue being experienced by other users encountering the same error, which is currently being mitigated by our product engineering teams. I believe that mitigation has already been rolled out and confirmed by some users. Please then reach out and let me know if this issue has been resolved for you or if you are still encountering this error. "